# How to delete columns from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Value 4 Value 5 Value 6

123     3       43      567     53      3

111     123     2       3       9       0

8       8       3       2       3       98
```

I have 5 columns where a user can write values. All the rest of the columns have to be invisible, or deleted. I don't want to blank or block them, or remove values from them. I want them to not exist.

Comment: Your question is extremely ambiguous. You are using terms like 'delete' and 'not exist' and at the same time you want them to be 'invisible'. Please edit your question and choose what you want: hide or remove?

Comment: What are you concerned the user will do if these extra columns aren't hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the **review** tab of excel, in the *changes* section, you'll need to `Allow Users to Edit Ranges` and define the ranges they can edit with the password.
2. Then right click the other columns and select **hide**.
3. Now back in the **review** tab, protect the workbook and put a different password in. Allow them to select locked and unlocked ranges.

Now they will be able to edit the defined ranges with the password for those, but not the rest of the sheet/book.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just select the columns, either by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and selecting contiguous columns or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for non-contiguous columns.

The right click on any of the column headers and 'Hide' the columns. That should give you the required result.

See this image
[image]

Comment: No, the user can change it back again. It's not a solution.

Comment: You did not mention that. Well the solution would be to 'Protect the Workbook'. Go to Review Tab> Protect Workbook> enter a password (the Structure should be Selected)

Comment: I love this solution, though it annoys me that 2013 has a white background. It used to look awesome in earlier versions, with that grey background. Made your sheet look more like an application!

Comment: @CLockeWork You have the option to change it to Light Gray and Dark Gray. Check in the options, General section.

Comment: True enough, but that's specific your theme, so if someone else has the white theme it won't look like that way for them :( Still, very much a first world problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to delete columns:

1. Select a column by clicking on the column header.
2. Click the delete dropdown.
3. Click on delete sheet columns.

[image]

Comment: I am not that stupid.

Comment: @user304610 Never said you where. Just a suggestion for a solution about the problem specified above.